# How to restart the Node.js Inspector after making changes to a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-inspector

Does anyone know a faster way to restart the debugger session?

When I edit a file while debugging using the Node.js inspector, I have to press `CTRL+ D` to exit the Node.js debugger client, then start the debugger again. I was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have just learned about the `restart` keyword, which can restart the Node.js debugger client:

```
debug> restart
```